# What is the best approach to handle email form abused by bots?

Tags: php, web-server, wordpress, email-bounces, blacklist-prevention

I just recently moved to a Dedicated Server hosting from a normal Reseller Hosting, and currently facing issue with email blacklisting.

One of my clients has about 4 contact forms that automatically send a receipt email to the user and to the administrative email when it's sent. I have placed a captcha to prevent spam & bot abuse which is working well.

**The problem is:** There are times where user types wrong email address which make the sending **invalid** or even **bouncing back**. (The website's traffic is about 400-800 visits per day, and there are about 10-25 contact form being used in a day.)

Sometimes it can go really bad (the bounce and invalid send) and the IP got blacklisted by BACKLASH and other email blacklisting tools. They think that we're sending spammy emails.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Should I just talk to my client and turn off the feature to automatically send email to customer? Or is there any better way to deal with blacklisting?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing something that can be used to send unsolicited email (the "receipt email to the user"). That's spam and, irrespective of the CAPTCHA it will be abused. I'd tell your client that the "receipt" email violates acceptable use policy with your host (because it probably does) and turn it off.